# How can I insert multiple li items each in a different row in mysql with a single click (jQuery, PHP, SQL)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

`<ul id="shopping-cart">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<button class="buy" role="button">Buy Items</button>`

Table:

`|++++++++++++++++++|
| id | product_name |
|+++++++++++++++++++|
| 1  | Item 1       |
| 2  | Item 2       |
|+++++++++++++++++++|`

I need to insert two items from the shopping cart (li items) in a history table in mysql with a single click. 
Any idea, How can I do?

Comment: Hey there - this feels like a very broad, general question. We can help you better if you post some code that you have tried, along with associated info like your DB schema, and ask us to help you fix a specific problem. Check out this link to get info on writing a great question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And check out this one to see what to avoid in your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @Camilo Rincón Welcome to SO. I would strongly advise you check this article and then edit your question with some of the suggested criteria you find there. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) This will help to ensure that you can actually get a viable answer for your question, which is quite broad without any reference code or any steps with which you have tried to this point. Best of luck.

Comment: As an aside, the HTML shown looks invalid: you shouldn't have a button element as a direct child of a ul element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert many values into SQL with a single command (though not recommend, use PDO), such as

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
```

( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )

If using jQuery, you can use `$.post()` to send data to your web server (PHP). Here's an example:

```
var items = []
$('li .item').each(function(index, item) {
    items.push({
        name: item.child('.name').text(),
        cost: parseFloat(item.child('.cost').text()),
    })
});
$.post("post.php", {
    data : JSON.stringify(items),
    contentType : 'application/json',
});
```

And in your `post.php`:

```
$items = json_decode($_POST['data']);
// Insert into DB
```

You should be using [Prepared Statements (PDO)](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to insert safely in your database.

Comment: thanks Charles! just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You use with Select2 multiple for saving more li with a single click, you can also read this for documentation and source https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2